# REST endpoint to replace a member of a group

Tags: rest, api-design, endpoint

There are multiple collections and each can be identified by a unique ID.  Withing each collection are multiple people and each can be identified by their employee ID.  Obviously, a single person cannot be in the same collection twice.

I will need to replace a given person with a new person in a given collection.

Should this be done using two endpoints:

```
DELETE /collections/123/employees/321
POST   /collections/123 {"employeeId": 222}
```

Or can it be done with one:

```
PUT /collections/123/employees/321 {"employeeId": 222}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PUT should be [idempotent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Idempotent):

> An HTTP method is idempotent if an identical request can be made once or several times in a row with the same effect while leaving the server in the same state. In other words, an idempotent method should not have any side-effects (except for keeping statistics). Implemented correctly, the GET, HEAD, PUT, and DELETE method are idempotent, but not the POST method.

What should happen in the back-end if you call:

```
PUT /collections/123/employees/321 {"employeeId": 222}
PUT /collections/123/employees/321 {"employeeId": 222}
PUT /collections/123/employees/321 {"employeeId": 222}
PUT /collections/123/employees/321 {"employeeId": 222}
```

If the 321 record no longer exists, how should it be handled? If the new employeeId already exists, how should it be handled?

Logically, to me, it would make more sense to keep them as two separate calls (removing the old member, and adding a new member). While you *could* handle this in a PUT request while keeping the request idempotent, it isn't very clear to a potential user what the intended functionality of this call is.

Comment: Thanks Thebluefish,  Given the four requests you showed, the first request would replace employee 321 with employee 222, and the next three would have no effect since employee 321 is no longer in the group.  Does this violate being idempotent?

Comment: As long as the end result is the same, it is idempotent. It isn't really self-descriptive though (does it make sense to PUT to a record that doesn't exist?), but as long as you can ensure it is idempotent, do whatever you feel makes the most sense to you.

Comment: I agree it is not descriptive, but it does save a trip to the server, and I am torn.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit, I might consider something like `POST /collections/123/employees/replace {"old": 321, "new": 222}`

Comment: Isn't doing so idempotent?  Maybe not the first request, but future requests after that...

Comment: In doing such a POST, I might return `{ "success": false, "status": "The user 321 does not exist!" }` in subsequent calls. The concept of a `/replace` is clear: Only add the new user if we are removing the old user. A similar PUT would have a slightly different concept: Ensure the old user does not exist and the new user does exist.